# Delphi - Control Dialog Form Show Status from a Thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, dialog

In my application I do a big quantity of task in a thread for example multiples querys to big database.
I created a dialog (custom form), with a progressbar and status bar that show at final user what do you do the soft, I can synchronize the progress status with callbackmode without problems.

My problem is how I can control that this Dialog (Custom Form) show in modal  until thread execute and can close when thread finalize.

Comment: Which do you need help with? Showing or closing?

Comment: The `OnTerminate` event of the thread seems like a good idea to signal the modal form to close.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can show easy the dialog form, with MyDialog.ShowModal;MyThread.Start();, the problem is how when the thread end the dialog close and soft come back to show main form.

Comment: Get your callback to set ModalResult of the modal form.

Comment: @LURD what is the better way to send the signal to the model form.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I do it in this way right now using callback to close the dialog form, but i think that exist a most elegant way.

Comment: What other option do you have? The code to close the modal form must be executed in the GUI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the thread before calling `ShowModal()`, or have the form's `OnShow` event start the thread.  Use the thread's `OnTerminate` event (which runs in the main thread) to `Close()` the form, which will cause `ShowModal()` to exit.  While the thread is running, it can use `TThread.Synchronize()`, or custom window messages, to update the form as needed.